# Citation style with initials only, as in [A99,BC35,DEFGH67]

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

Is there an already-made style that does that? The closest I have produces *three letters* for single authors, which seems weird to me.  As in [God31] instead of [G31].

Comment: This citation style was common when papers were typewritten and it was almost impossible to know in advance all the citations; it's quite out of fashion, nowadays, and without much regret. Its modern descendant is “author-year” style.

Comment: I am not sure why other style are better.  What is the point of writing God31 but GE32?

Comment: I'm sure this is not the best style anyway. Use author-year or numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by creating a label template as described in §4.5.5 of the `biblatex` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,minalphanames=3]{biblatex}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
   \labelelement{
     \field[final]{shorthand}
     \field{label}
     \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
   }
   \labelelement{
     \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
   }
}
 \DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
   \namepart[use=true, pre=true, strwidth=1, compound=true]{prefix} 
   \namepart{family}
}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{padhye,murray,glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In this example I've set `minalphanames` to be three, which will produce initials up to 3 authors, and then add a `+` for the others. You can change these values (and also `maxalphanames`) as you see fit.

[image: output of code]

***How to do this in LyX***

I don't fully understand how LyX interacts with the LaTeX preamble, and putting the code into it doesn't seem to work. But there is a way to do it. Make the following file named `myalpha.bbx` in the folder where your LyX document is or in your local `texmf` folder:  `<path-to-local-texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx` (create this folder if it doesn't exist.)

```
\ProvidesFile{myalpha.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{alphabetic}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
   \labelelement{
     \field[final]{shorthand}
     \field{label}
     \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
   }
   \labelelement{
     \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
   }
}
 \DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
   \namepart[use=true, pre=true, strwidth=1, compound=true]{prefix} 
   \namepart{family}
}
```

Then in your Document Settings -> Bibliography use `myalpha` as the `bibliography` style, and `alphabetic` as the citation style, and add the `minalphanames=3` to the citation style options, as in this screen shot. Ignore the fact that the "Variant" selection is "Author-Year" as this will be overridden by the styles you choose separately.

At least with my limited testing (having never used LyX) this seems to work.

[image: LyX screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! Can this be put into a style file, or is there an existing package that does this?  I'm having trouble incorporating this in my lyx document, apparently because lyx is trying to manage the bibliography.

Comment: @Manu I've added a LyX solution.